# Ungrouping Separate Processes From The Taskbar

Tags: c++, windows, qt, taskbar

I'm writing an application using C++ and Qt which the user can run multiple instances of on the same machine. Each instance of the application has two to three windows associated with them. At the moment, all instances of the application and their windows are grouped together in the taskbar (top image). I want each process to have its own group in the taskbar (bottom image). How can this be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a different application ID for certain of the windows, or certain of the processes. This is what Windows uses to determine whether to group the icons or not.

Please see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx

---

Pertinent quote:

Setting the application ID for a process involves a call to the `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` Win32 function from shell32.dll. Setting the application ID for a window requires calling the `SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow` function and then manipulating the returned `IPropertyStore` object. The following example shows you how to do this:

```
PROPVARIANT pv; 
InitPropVariantFromString(L"MyAppID", &pv);
IPropertyStore* pps;
VERIFY(SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pps))); 
VERIFY(pps->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, pv)); 
VERIFY(pps->Commit());
```

Comment: Links can go bad. You should include the details of how to do the ungrouping here in the answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Added a quote from the article.

Comment: This is the right way to go about it. Use a unique AppUserModeId.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will separate taskbar according to processID. The disadvantage is that the pinning does not work well.

```
 OSVERSIONINFO v;

 v.dwOSVersionInfoSize= sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
 GetVersionEx(&v);

 if (v.dwMajorVersion == 6 && v.dwMinorVersion > 1 || v.dwMajorVersion > 6)
 {
    //on Windows 7 or higher ungroup taskbar for separate process
    DWORD currentProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    WCHAR AppID[100];
    swprintf(AppID, sizeof(AppID) / sizeof(AppID[0]), L"AppID%u", currentProcessId);
    SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(AppID);
 }
```

Comment: This has to run during startup of application though no? As it won't work once windows have shown?